NodeGroup launch templates ( stop-hibernate ) not translating onto the ASG launch templates
I've enabled stop-hibernate behavior on launch template associated to the NodeGroup in EKS

But this is not translating onto the ASG Launch templates that EKS auto-creates ?

Looking for hibernating the EC2 instances that EKS creates, but due to this inconsistency of not translating the hibernate options specified on the NodeGroup Launch Template to ASG Launch Templates, the EC2 instance the gets created eventually doesn't show the option to hibernate?
